# Regex matching current year date

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I just started to learn regex. I created a regex for my project username where I want:

- 2 digits of day
- 2 digits of month
- last 2 digits of current year
- finally last 2  digits of the year after 4 years

i.e. I need to match output something like that:

```
23071923
```

where:

- 23 is the current day(dd)
- 07 is the month (mm)
- 19 is current year(YY)
- 23 is the year after 4 years(yy)

But I am confused how will it match the current year and only take last 2 digits of the year. and how i can match the end of regex is correct and is 4 added in the year or not?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that contains your input and expected outputs.

Comment: *and last 2 digits of year and finally last 2 digits of the year* ???

Comment: i want last two digits of current year as from 2019 just 19. and last two digits of the year after 4 years .i.e. 2019+4= 2023 .from 2023 need just 23.

Comment: Please, update your question with what you *have* and what you *need*. And regex doesn't do any math.

Comment: Now it's more clearer. What's the example of input string?

Comment: 23071923 input is somewhat like this. English is not my mother tongue so, i don't know how to make my question more clearer.

Comment: Are you trying to use regex to _determine_ or _validate_ the current year? No, regex doesn't do that. What programming language are you using?

Comment: i'm working with .net c# MVC4 . just wanted to validate the current year because where i need this it is registering student on that specific date and their date of completion of degree is included in their registration no

Comment: It looks like you're trying to construct a string/username (as opposed to matching/validating an existing one). In other words, given a specific date, generate a string that represents the current date in the format `ddMMyy` followed by `yy` representing the current year +4. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you need Regex in this case.  If you want to validate a date is correct simply use DateTime.TryParse().  Regex is for parsing strings and wan't meant for validating a DATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the trick with replacing the input string with modified string, which does math:

```
var x = "23071923";
var x2 = Regex.Replace(x, @"^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$", m =>
         m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[2].Value + m.Groups[3].Value +
         (int.Parse(m.Groups[3].Value) + 4));
bool is_match = x == x2;
```